# Remove playback speed control

Tags: iphone, podcasts, podcasts.app, apple-watch

I like that my Apple Watch (series 3) shows a Now Playing screen whilst listening to a Podcast on my iPhone; however I often accidentally press the playback speed button on it. This is annoying and frustrating and personally it's a function I never have a use for. Is there any way I can remove, disable or lock this functionality?

thank you

Comment: Are you referring to the small complication that shows up on the top of the screen or do you mean that the Now Playing screen takes-up the entire screen when using audio apps?

Comment: Don't know about that, but you could probably get around it with a 3rd party podcast app. It might be worth a try if there's no other way. I've never used this with the Apple Watch, but I'd recommend you try [‎Castro](https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id1080840241#?platform=appleWatch).

Comment: @fsb the latter

Comment: Pretty much all 3rd party podcast apps have a way to transfer podcasts from Apples podcast app. I'm personally a big fan of how Castro's queue feature works.

Comment: this trips me up once a day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with the default Now Playing screen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific way to disable the speed control.  It's part of the Now Playing screen.  The only way to remove this is to stop the Now Playing screen from being automatically displayed in the first place.

[Source](https://www.imore.com/how-stop-apple-watch-launching-now-playing):

"The Now Playing app on the Apple Watch offers quick access to controls for your music and other audio on your Apple devices, particularly your iPhone. But by default, Now Playing pops up automatically, and that can get really annoying, especially if you're trying to keep an eye on a timer and your Apple Watch keeps switching over to Now Playing."

### How to stop Now Playing from launching on your Apple Watch

1. Press the Digital Crown on your Apple Watch.
2. Tap `Settings` on the list of apps or in the grid view.
3. Tap `General`.
   [image]
4. Tap `Wake Screen`.
5. Tap the switch next to `Auto-Launch Audio Apps` so it's in the gray "off" position.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you. But I did specifically say I enjoy this feature.

Comment: Yes, you did.  And I specifically stated that there's no way to do what you're looking for so this is the only way to achieve your goal.